# Действия кнопки в Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Пытаюсь уже на протяжении недели изучить вопрос по "action" в button в SwiftUI. Как мне при нажатии кнопки переходить на новое окно, пусть к примеру будет это "windowTwo.swift"? Перелопатил если не весь рунет, то большую часть, англоязычный сегмент интернета - тоже не дал результата...

[image: Изображение из приложения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ - использовать `NavigationLink` или `NavigationButton`

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("DetailView")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showsDetailViewController = false

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                Text("Navigate")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если хочется использовать именно действие кнопки `Button`, то можно сделать так. Правда в данном случае экран будет показан в модальном виде.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showsDetailViewController = false

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.showsDetailViewController = true
                }) {
                    Text("Navigate")
                }
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showsDetailViewController) {
            DetailView()
        }
    }
}
```

Еще один вариант навигации [отсюда](https://ericasadun.com/2019/06/16/swiftui-modal-presentation/)

```
struct LiveView: View {
  @State var isPresented = false

  var modalPresentation: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Text("Hello World")
        .font(.caption)
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Modal Contents"))
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: { self.isPresented = false } ) { Text("Done") })
    }
  }

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      NavigationButton(destination: Text("Hello World")
        .font(.caption)
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Detail View Contents"))
      ) {
        Text("Show Detail View")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Welcome"))
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
          Button(action: { self.isPresented = true }) { Text("Show Modal") })
      }
      .presentation( isPresented ? Modal(modalPresentation, onDismiss: { self.isPresented.toggle() }) : nil )
  }
}
```